# Can werecoyotes/werejaguars form packs?

Tags: werewolf, shape-shifter, teen-wolf

In the Teen Wolf universe, can werecoyotes form packs like werewolves can? I mean the supernatural way (red eyes, betas, alphas, etc.) not just a bunch of supernatural not killing each other.

Comment: You'll have to limit your question to a specific book or film or something.

Comment: @Radhil I mean whatever setting

Comment: @miltonaut Well, since someone *edited out* the tag which made the specific setting clear ...

Comment: @Randal'Thor made a rollback

Comment: @Paulie_D Please be more careful when editing. You actually made this question *less clear* by removing the franchise tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes.

From the [Teen Wolf Wiki](http://www.teenwolfwiki.com/werecoyote) (emphasis mine):

> Like all canine werecreatures, **when a werecoyote follows an alpha, joining his pack, they receive symbiotic maturity and power by being a packmate.** They become more accomplished in using their supernatural abilities, their powers amplifying and their self-control and prowess improving. Malia Tate, as a member of Scott's Pack, with Scott being her alpha, her preternatural strength, endurance, speed, agility and skill with using her supernatural abilities have improved since joining. **Her eyes also flash blue in response to Scott's alpha's roar, displaying she becomes stronger from the support of being in his pack, establishing herself as a beta werecoyote.**